# Set Particular Sprite Image as full background Image of the page

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) Image as Sprite Image.

I want to make the first image of House as Background Image of entire web page. In Other words I want to set background image to body tag of the page.

How to achieve this using CSS?

Comment: use background-position property and set X and Y values.. reference link here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Yes I tried but did not get how to display that particular House Image to full background of the web page

Comment: @ChandraShekhar 
Yes I tried it by setting the background position property but it is repeating everywhere on page
Refer this Js fiddel
https://jsfiddle.net/pt235wx7/

Comment: Even when I set background-repeat: none It displays all 3 images

Comment: I also set `background-position` property and `background-repeat` property in JS fiddle but But hard luck.
Refer this link.
https://jsfiddle.net/pt235wx7/6/